# MODx Rewrite for htaccess to logical sup page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, modx-revolution

Need a little bit of help, we've got a database setup with friendly URLs to do the output from the database - this all works fine, however i'm now having to add a physical subdirectory into the structure and basically its breaking and my `htaccess` skills are nil.

Here's what I have for the virtual database URLS.

```
RewriteRule ^resources/([^/]*)/(.+)$ index.php?q=resources/$1-display/&req=$1/$2 [L]
```

This makes the url to appears as `domain.com/resources/page/alias`

page has a full alias of page-display hence the -display part.

Now, I want to move an existing page in the `CMS` that was `domain.com/alias` and move it to

```
 domain.com/resources/subfolder/alias
```

The problem I have is as follows.

If I move the physical page to

```
 domain.com/resources/[document] -
```

All works fine, it reads as

```
domain.com/resources/alias
```

If i move it to

```
domain.com/resources/subfolder/[document]
```

It explodes and throws a error

I've tried

```
RewriteRule ^resources/([^/]*)/(.+)$ index.php?q=resources/subfolder/$1/$2 [L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^resources/subfolder/(.+)$ index.php?q=resources/subfolder/$1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^resources/subfolder/(.+)$ index.php?q=resources/subfolder/$1/ [L]
```

But to no avail, anyone got any ideas as I'm not a expert in `htaccess` by any means but I need to get this page up :/

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you clarify this further? I'm confused about if you want a rewrite or a file moved. What is the current actual path of the file? Is it `index.php?q=alias`? What is the working request and what do you want the rewrite to look like?

Comment: Sorry its a page resource within modx, i need to move it in the heriarchical tree.

Its current location is at domain.com/this-is-the-page

but it needs to be moved to 

domain.com/resources/infographics/this-is-the-page

the problem is a mojority of the pages under /resources/ are dynamically generated to be like

resources/case-study/case-study-article or resources/media-coverage/media-coverage-article 

anything can be after the /resources/random-page-name but as soon as you add a logical subfolder it fails

hope that helps clarify a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with modx but think that your existing RewriteRule may be conflicting with  the page at its new location.

If this *is* the case, you could get around it by adding a condition that makes an exception to the rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/resources/infographics
  RewriteRule ^resources/([^/]*)/(.+)$ index.php?q=resources/$1-display/&req=$1/$2 [L]
```

This assumes that a request to `/resources/infographics/this-is-the-page` would work fine after you've moved the page in the CMS and the existing rule is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Default htaccess file for modx

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]



# Rewrite secure requests properly to prevent SSL cert warnings, e.g. prevent 
# https://www.example.com when your cert only allows https://secure.example.com
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
#RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]



# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Check [this](https://allhtaccess.info/modx-default-htaccess-file/) for full htaccess file